# True or False. Non parallel lines in 3-space.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, coordinate-systems

Two non parallel lines in 3 space must intersect in at least one point.
True or False?
I say false because you can have two perpendicular lines on x and y, but on a different "level" of the z-axis.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right :-). Look under "skew lines" in Wikipedia.

Comment: absolutely right! btw, they're called **skew lines**  :  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SkewLines.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right. Here is a more general fact: In a vector space $V$ of dimension $m$, and numbers $k,l$ with $k+l<m$ generically two affine subspaces of dimensions $k$ and $l$ do not intersect.